# Have multiple errors in every project in eclipse + can't start app on device through intelliJ

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, intellij-idea

I'm been having trouble developing lately, recently i tried to import a project and ended up downloading an older SDK, I'm new to developing so I'm not really sure what I've done.
After doing this in eclipse i got errors in all my projects that used to work, errors like "the import android.os cannot be resolved","Activity cannot be resolved to a type"... basicly every line is an error... I also have IntelliJ and projects from there cannot be uploaded to my phone either... please help me solve this, it's driving me crazy!

screenshot of eclipse: http://imageshack.com/a/img208/603/ce52.png

IntelliJ logcat:

03-17 23:48:29.991      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:29.991      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:30.319      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:30.319      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:30.653      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:30.653      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:30.983     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:30.984     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:31.313     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:31.313     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:31.649      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:31.650      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:31.985      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:31.985      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:32.317      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:32.317      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:32.639     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:32.639     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:32.970     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:32.970     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:33.298      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:33.298      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:33.632      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:33.632      258-258/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:33.965      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:33.965      258-473/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:34.240      258-324/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove wlan0 default 192.168.1.1 32 0.0.0.0} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)}
03-17 23:48:34.244      258-324/? E/ConnectivityService﹕ Exception trying to remove a route: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native dameon to add routes - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface route remove wlan0 default 0.0.0.0 0 192.168.1.1} failed with code 400 : {Failed to remove route from default table (No such process)}
03-17 23:48:34.400     258-5416/? E/StateMachine﹕ DhcpStateMachine - unhandledMessage: msg.what=-1
03-17 23:48:34.514     258-1706/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:34.514     258-1706/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:34.839     258-1881/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:34.839     258-1881/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:35.175      258-468/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:35.175      258-468/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:35.501     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:35.501     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:35.824     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:35.824     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:36.160      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:36.161      258-268/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:36.493     258-1881/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:36.493     258-1881/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:36.815      258-468/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:36.816      258-468/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:37.155     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:37.155     258-1876/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:37.314      258-325/? E/StateMachine﹕ TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
03-17 23:48:37.506      258-269/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:37.506      258-269/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:37.855      258-519/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:37.855      258-519/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget
03-17 23:48:38.245     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id = com.android.server.AppWidgetService$AppWidgetId@4237fb88id.host = com.jrdcom.launcher
03-17 23:48:38.245     258-1705/? E/AppWidgetService﹕ id.provider = com.jrdcom.musicwidget........and goes on forever...

Answer (score 0):

try running the Android sdk manager ("android" on linux) and ensure you have everything (ie the SDKs you need) installed. There are oodles of resources on the web explaining how to set up your SDK. Check your android sdk environmentals point to the correct place - again there are many resources dedicated to this but you dont mention your OS/Platform. On my linux system its set in my.bash_env thus:

```
export ANDROIDSDK="${HOME}"/development/android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME="${HOME}"/development/android/sdk
PATH=${ANDROIDSDK}/tools:${ANDROIDSDK}/platform-tools:${PATH}
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

Ensure you have selected the correct SDK for building your project in the IDE. Ensure you have selected the correct TARGET min and MAX versions for your project : and ensure they are proprely installed as I stated in the first sentence above. Good luck.